# trouble adding values to a new List from a list stored in a hashmap - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I've been hunting around for a way to do this and it is driving me mad!

What I'm trying to do is as follows:

I have a HashMap:

```
qualifiedCompetitors = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

The values I'm assigning to the hashmap are:

```
String[] events = {"Helicopter", "Amphibious", 
                     "4x4", "Fire Engine"};

String[][] competitors = 
{
   {"Greg", "Will", "Fleur", "Bill", "Bella", "Sally", "Olive", "Sal", "Dora", "Chas"}, 
   {"Yuri", "Abe", "Tim", "Fleur", "Bonnie", "Vera", "Ed", "Dan", "Jill", "Rose", "Zoe"}, 
   {"Tim", "Fleur", "Will",  "Bill", "Bella", "Dan", "Jill", "Rose", "Greg",  "Abe", "Sally", "Yuri", "Olive", "Sal", "Jim"}, 
   {"Jill", "Rose", "Greg", "Abe", "Bonnie", "Vera", "Ed", "Zoe", "Ben", "Freda", "Chuck", "Fred"}
};
```

the key sting is the name of an event and the List is a list of competitors. I want to build a new list of all the competitors.

So I've tried various things like:

```
ListOfAllqualifiedCompetitors = new ArrayList(qualifiedCompetitors.values());
```

and then iterating through the hashmap:

```
Collection allCompetitors = qualifiedCompetitors.values();

System.out.println("Values of Collection created from Hashtable are :");
//iterate through the collection
Iterator itr = allDrivers.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
  System.out.println(itr.next());
```

To see what vales I get, which is fine, but I cannot then add them a new list? I know I'm missing something obvious any suggestions?

Comment: *Why* can't you add them to the list?  What code doesn't work, and *why* doesn't it work?

Comment: so If I try:
    ListOfAllqualifiedCompetitors = new ArrayList(qualifiedCompetitors.values());

I cannot compile (cannot find symbol).

and if try and iterate using something like the above I get each value back as an incompatible type.

Comment: Do you want one list of all competitors, or a list of a list of competitors?  For the former, see my answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I *think* you're saying is that you have a map of `String` to `List<String>` and you want to accumulate all of the `List<String>` into a single long list.  If that's the case:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> eventsToCompetitors;
final List<String> allCompetitors;

eventsToCompetitors = ...

allCompetitors = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Collection<String> competitors : eventsToCompetitors.values())
{
  allCompetitors.addAll(competitors);
}
```

Comment: I am then using this new list to create a treeset as this will remove the duplicates and sort them, would it make more sense to create a treeset first and populate that rather than the list?

Comment: @damagedgoods, that's what Sets are for afterall.  They wouldn't be much good if they didn't remove duplicates.  Though unless you have a reason to, use HashSet rather than TreeSet.

Comment: @Greg_Kopff, Map.values() returns a Set, not a List, so this wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Neil: ah yes, `values()` returns a `Collection` - I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> allCompetitors = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Set<String> competitors : qualifiedCompetitors.values()) {
    allCompetitors.addAll(competitors);
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: yup - that worked if I changed the for each from Set<String> to List<String>. Thx